# Triggering a Jenkins build using node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, jenkins, build

I have a jenkins job that takes a file as an input. The job reads the input file and then processes the job.

I am trying to run a jenkins job from node js script. I am able to run the particular job using the jenkins api for npm.

My problem is that I am not able to run the job by passing the file required.

In Jenkins, I have to find the particular job and then migrate to it and then click "Build with parameters" and then select the file and build.

I am trying to uncomplicate this by having a react UI that takes a file as input and submits it to the node js script. Now that script has to upload the file to Jenkins and then build the job.

Node js code is,

```
var file0 = '/Users/m0a00pf/Documents/react-js/asda/src/files/APA.csv';
exports.buildJenkinsJob = function buildJenkinsJob(){
    jenkins.job.build({"name":"Create a job",
                    "parameters":
                        {
                             "name": "\\src\\main\\resources\\com\\asda\\qa\\data\\APA\\APA.csv", "file": file0
                        }
                    }
                    ,function(err, data){
        if(err)
            throw err;
        else
            console.log(data);
    });
}
```

The parameters part is not working. when I run.

```
jenkins.job.build({"Create a job"});
```

this works fine.

Comment: Pushing a file to the Jenkins server sounds like an unusual case.  I think it's more common to have Jenkins pull needed files from somewhere.  Is that possible in your case?

Comment: Your question is still missing steps. Lay out the problem then share related the code. Beyond the ["How to ask"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) advice, you also need to start by stating the question in a way that focuses on what gap remains _after_ your research. Then describe your strategy thus far, code setup + conditions, and the errors/issues. Also state 'obvious' context that you already know, so that people understand what you have tried. See also [1](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Changed the options as,

```
    var options = {
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost/job/JobName/buildWithParameters?delay=0sec&Jenkins-Crumb=asdf345672das',
      auth : {
           username : jenkins.username,
           password : jenkins.password
      },
      headers:
       {
        'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW'
       },
      body:
       {
        'fileParameterName' :
                    { value: fs.createReadStream(absoluteFilePath), options: { filename: FileName, contentType: null } },
         'param': 'value'
       }

    };
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a plain JS way of doing this, with just popular libraries such as Axios and [form-data](https://www.npmjs.com/package/form-data)

```
var axios = require('axios');
var FormData = require('form-data');
var fs = require('fs');
var data = new FormData();

const jenkinsUrl = 'http://example_jenkins_server_url.com/job/<JOB_NAME>/build';
// notice the URL has build not buildWithParameters if the job has file parameters. ^
const userName = 'example_user';
const password = 'example_pass'

const params = {"parameter": [
  // file0 here is the field name we are appending to data object, 
  // this informs Jenkins which file maps to which job parameter, so even multiple file uploads can be done using this approach!
  {"name":"<Name Of file parameter in Job>", "file":"file0"}
  // incase you have additional string parameters you need to pass add it here. 
  {"name": "StringParam1", "value": "value"}
]}

data.append('file0', fs.createReadStream(<full file path>));
data.append('json', JSON.stringify(params));

var config = {
  method: 'post',
  url: jenkinsUrl,
  headers: { 
    Authorization: `Basic ${Buffer.from(`${userName}:${password}`).toString('base64')}`,
    ...data.getHeaders()
  },
  data : data
};

axios(config)
.then(function (response) {
  console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data));
})
```